# Accessing Form Authentication Ticket

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am storing user details with form authentication cookie.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new  FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Timeout)false};

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(
FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,encryptedTicket);    

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

How can I get back the added cookie and user detail (authTicket)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can retrieve the [`FormsAuthenticationTicket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) using code similar to the following:

```
// Retrieves the cookie that contains your custom FormsAuthenticationTicket.
HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

// Decrypts the FormsAuthenticationTicket that is held in the cookie's .Value property.
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

// The "authTicket" variable now contains your original, custom FormsAuthenticationTicket,
// complete with User-specific custom data.  You can then check that the FormsAuthenticationTicket's
// .Name property is for the correct user, and perform the relevant functions with the ticket.
// Here, we simply write the user-specific data to the Http Response stream.
if (authTicket.Name == txtUserName.Text)
{
    Response.Write(authTicket.UserData);
}
```

The above code makes reference to things like `txtUserName.Text`, so here's a complete .ASPX page that you can paste into an empty ASP.NET webform to see how it works:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Timeout = 15.00;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,txtUserName.Text,
                    DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Timeout), false, "This is my secret user-specific data");

            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,encryptedTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieves the cookie that contains your custom FormsAuthenticationTicket.
            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            // Decrypts the FormsAuthenticationTicket that is held in the cookie's .Value property.
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            // The "authTicket" variable now contains your original, custom FormsAuthenticationTicket,
            // complete with User-specific custom data.  You can then check that the FormsAuthenticationTicket's
            // .Name property is for the correct user, and perform the relevant functions with the ticket.
            // Here, we simply write the user-specific data to the Http Response stream.
            if (authTicket.Name == txtUserName.Text)
            {
                Response.Write(authTicket.UserData);
            }
        }
    }        
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Forms Authentication Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        UserName:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```